# Xpages Calendar View

Tags: calendar, xpages

[image: Entry Screenshot]
[image: Calendar view screenshot]

on my one of my XPages i have to use Calendar view. There is a Notes View. I will use it as XPages Data source then the calendar will Show the data as weekly, Daily and monthly.

is there any sample, suggestion?
I found this but there is no sample code or the way how to do?
https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?documentId=E78FED69C5D805E0862576C50050D88B

Regards
C.A.
[image: ScreenSHot of REST Services]

Comment: Bear in mind that this project pre-dated the release of XPages Extension Library, which has a calendar view component based on iNotes calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download an [ExtLib version](https://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/473B2FE80FD6EA0986257EEB003FA2FF) from OpenNTF and get the example database "**XPagesExt.nsf**" from "ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v....zip" file. XPages "**DWA_iNotesRest.xsp**" and "**DWA_LocalCalendarView.xsp**" show you how to create a calendar in XPages.

You can find another good example in template "TeamRoom (9)". Create a new database on your server based on this template

[image]

and have a look at XPage "calendar" with included custom control "calendarView".

*Update*

I created a simple example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:restService
        id="restService1"
        pathInfo="/inoteslegacyjson"
        preventDojoStore="false">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:calendarJsonLegacyService
                viewName="calendar"
                contentType="text/plain"
                colCalendarDate="StartDateTime"
                colEndTime="EndDateTime"
                colSubject="Subject"
                colChair="Chair">
            </xe:calendarJsonLegacyService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>

    <xe:calendarView
        id="calendarView1"
        type="W"
        storeComponentId="restService1"
        style="width:100%">
    </xe:calendarView>
</xp:view>
```

The **view** is named "calendar"

[image]

View's first sorted(!) column has to be the start date/time.
Its programmatic column name is matched to `colCalendarDate`.

[image]
[image]

The other three columns are matched the same way.

Comment: I found the way out. Thank you.

but i cannot see the entry on calendar view :( how is that possible? i think i should see them. I have 3 entries but i cannot see them :(

I added my screenshots. Please find them at the top of this page

Comment: Please show your relevant XPages/SSJS code. It looks to me as your calendar is not correctly connected to database's view.

Comment: as you mentioned above i tried to go to deeper as much as l could.
I had 2 problems. 
i finally found that REST services did not connect to Lotus Notes view. then the version of Internet Explorer is 11. It does not work on it. I tried with IE8 it worked.

Comment: Hi Knut;

have you ever tried to connect normal view to be shown on a inotes Calendar view with RestServices.? If you have don this before which rest services did you use? I think I have a little bit missing logic point on me. If i got this logic i might be able to manage that :)

Comment: Do you use the  the "normal" calendar view "($Calendar) | Calendar" of mail boxes or an own view?

Comment: No i don't. :( I have my own. 

I have a myapproval.nsf 
I have a normal lotus notes view not calendar view. 
i have 4 columns on that view. (startDate, endDate, Subject, Responsibles). 
according to this architechture I just want to show datas in a calendar (iNotes Calendar) 
What i don't understand is does that LotusView has to be calendar style or normal stye and which JSon services do i have to use for calendar? (i put a screenshot top of this page)

Comment: Define your view's columns in rest service like `colStartTime="startDate"` so the rest service knows where to find the data for calendar. TeamRoom uses an own view and there you can see how to define such own columns in rest service definition.

Comment: You mean I have to use calendarJsonLegacyService . i got it 
Thank yok.

Comment: Hi;
Thanks for your effot to help me to solve my problem. I tried older version of IE11 i can get all datas to iNotesCalendar but with IE11 i cannot. as far as i understanda i should change the behavior of IE11.
i need to add something to application theme or in to page resources something like that. 
Do you know the where to put the code?

Comment: This fixed my problem :) 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21967914