# People on vacation in Calendar View in XPages

Tags: xpages

I would like to see all people vacation plans in Calendar view in XPages. But which design element i have to use i do not know. 
I know it's not the right place to ask this kind of question but I really do not know where to start...

Comment: Do you mean vacation (and not "vocation")?

Comment: Yes, Holiday, vacation..

Comment: So are you looking for where vacation data are stored? or are you looking for a view to create a calendar?

Comment: I would like to create a calendar view to see who is on vacation. Not in a standart viewPanel.  I tried inotes Calendar view. I think this is the only Design element that i can use for. For example this week who are out of office(Means vacation)  I can see in Calendar view. It is better than a normal ViewPanel. I just would like to use better visual interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673230/xpages-calendar-view

Comment: It's my question also :)). This is ot working in IE11. It works with google chrome but not IE 11. So This does not solv my problem. :( The data in view cannot be displayed in IE 11.

Comment: But you answered your own question saying that this fixed your problem: www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21967914 which is the same as what Per has said in his answer. As such, I'm not sure what it is you're asking?

Comment: Thank you. What i am asking is for example;
A person from my company who is going to be on his vacation let's say next week. I can see him in a view but I would like to change my view to a calendar view. UPDATED my question with a screenshot.  So for example I will be on vacation starting 15.10.2018 - turning back to work 21.10.2018. 
I should see mySelf in a calendar view days of 15,16,17,18,19 and 20th...

Comment: Have a look at the question you already asked. You accepted an answer from Knut, which tells you exactly how to get an example. He even went as far as to include his own simple example

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the `calenderView`control to work with IE11 you need to tell the page to be rendered for IE10:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:        
    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10"); 
}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```